# Возврат значения из потока

Tags: c++, многопоточность, функции

Надо, чтобы возвращаемое значение `с` можно было использовать как-то в `int main()`. Как в случае передачи аргументов функции в поток принять возвращаемое значение функции для дальнейших операций с ней?

```
int tr(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 4;
    int b = 5;
    mutex mtx;
    thread t1(tr, a, b, ref(mtx));
}
```

Comment: В POSIX реализации потоков [pthread_join](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) доставляет значение, из [pthread_exit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html)

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь не потоком, а `async`:

```
auto fut = async(tr,a,b);
...
int result = fut.get();
```

Примерно так.

Answer (score 1):

Значение, возвращаемое в функции, связанной с потоком `std::thread`, игнорируется. То есть при имеющейся сигнатуре вернуть его в `main` не получится. Нужно либо передать его как ссылочный аргумент `std::ref` с модификацией сигнатуры и последующим ожиданием завершения потока через `join`, либо использовать упомянутый в соседнем ответе `std::async`.

Comment: Либо использовать packaged_task

Answer (score -1):

```
Void tr(int a, int b. int* res)
{
    *res= a + b;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 4;
    int b = 5;
    int res;
    mutex mtx;
    thread t1(tr, a, b, &res, ref(mtx));
}
```